# Simple HTTP login via REST in an AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm new to programming and Android and it is my first attempt to program an app but I'm already stuck with the login. The login has to be connected with an server and with the help of an get request, I'll get json data which I can use to verify the login data (username). The persons who are allowed to use the app are already in the database. It is supposed to be simple. In this forum, I could only find solutions with `HTTPClient` etc. but it doesn't work anymore only with `HTTPURLConnection`. I used the LoginActivity template

This is my code (I don't also have any experience to use JSON Data). This is the structure of our JSON DATA:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "firstName": "xx",
  "lastName": "xy",
  "fullName": "xx xy"
}

public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

       final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
       final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
       final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
        // attempt authentication against a network service.
        //InputStream is;


        URL url = null;
        try {
            String username = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            String inputLine;
            String result;

            url = new URL("URL//");
            //Connection with database
            urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //Connect with database
            //urlConnection.connect();
            //Open stream;
            //is=urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //Set methods and timeouts
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            //Connect to our URL
            urlConnection.connect();

            //TODO
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            //Create a new InputStreamReader
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new
                    InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            //Create a new buffered reader and String Builder
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            //Check if the line we are reading is not null
            while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }

            //Close our InputStream and Buffered reader
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();

            //Set our result equal to our stringBuilder
            result = stringBuilder.toString();

            //Proceed in function of status code response
            int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return false;

        /*for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

I also have this in a Http Service Class:
I have these methods in my class httpservice: How can I use this?

private HttpURLConnection setUpConnection(String url, Credentials credentials) throws IOException {
        URL reqUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) reqUrl.openConnection();

```
    if (credentials != null && !credentials.getPassword().isEmpty() && !credentials.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", createBasicAuthString(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword()));
    }
    return urlConnection;
}


/**
 * Creates the String for the Authorization Header
 *
 * @param user
 * @param password
 * @return
 */
private String createBasicAuthString(String user, String password) {
    String notEncoded = user + ":" + password;
    String encodedAuth = Base64.encodeToString(notEncoded.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return "Basic " + encodedAuth;
}
```

Comment: `url = new URL("URL//");` ??? Please post a normal url.

Comment: `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");`. You have already set the request method. Dont do it twice.

Comment: `urlConnection.setDoInput(true);`. That you should do before .connect() statement.

Comment: You are not sending email, two usernames and a password. So how could this code ever work?

Comment: `The login has to be connected with an server and with the help of an get request, I'll get json data which I can use to verify the login data (username). ` Dont understand a word. Normally you would send username and password to a server. And the server would verify them  And if you get json as response from the server then it is not you/android app who should check username. As that has been done by the server. What your android app would see in the json response is if the server accepted the login try. Please edit your post and tell better what you want.

Comment: Further it is strange that for login a get request is used.

Comment: I hopefull specified my post - including two methods from the http service

Comment: Please format your second code block. Not all code is in it. Dont you see?

Answer (score 0):

**Parse Your JSON Data like this,**

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Your_Sring_data);
 String  id= jsonObject.getJsonString("id");
 String firstName= jsonObject.getJsonString("firstName");
 String lastName= jsonObject.getJsonString("lastName");
 String fullName= jsonObject.getJsonString("fullName");
```

**and Return Response string instead of boolean success variable in doInBackground() method and parse that string through above code**